# android market action bar working on gingerbread..?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have been looking into the action bar as it may be useful in an application I'm building, however I have read that it will only work on API level 11 minimum. If that is the case, how is the android market using the action bar on gingerbread (API level10)?

Answer (score 6):

That version of Android Market isn't using the framework's ActionBar.  It's possible to implement one yourself, since it's just a bar that sits at the top of all the views in your layout.

If you'd like to implement the ActionBar in your own app, and don't feel like writing one from scratch, you have a couple of options:

-Start with the [ActionBarCompat sample code](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html)
-Use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/), a third party ActionBar.

Comment: Ohh that sort of makes sense, and I have been looking into actionbarsherlock and the greendroid project, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Kibria I asked myself that question a couple of weeks ago. Take a look at ActionBarCompat project from the Android developers page:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html

> This sample shows how to use the action bar design pattern on pre-API 11 devices and the built-in ActionBar on devices supporting API 11 or greater.

As it says, it allows you to have action bars on pre-API 11 devices and it works like a charm.

You can find the full source code inside the samples dir of a recent platform (I've tried inside platform 14 samples and found it there).

So if you are considering using an ActionBar for your app and want to be compatible, just go ahead take a look at that example an use it as a guide for your app.
Any doubt please feel free to ask.

[edit] You can also give a try to the ActionBarSherlock ( http://actionbarsherlock.com/ ) if you just want a straightforward solution and avoid taking a look at the code.
This is an extension of the library I first quoted and its goal is to simplify the use of the ActionBar across all Android platforms.
There is a usage guide that can be found in: http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html

Comment: Yeah I have read that and got quite confused at first what it meant by pre-API11 but now it seems to make sense, thank you!